# some error checking if string contains other string using the method IN

Tags: python

#### this is my code :

```py
    print('the STRING contains [tudo, ta OU esta] ?')
    print(STRING in ['tudo','ta','esta'])
    print('\n the STRING contains [bem OU bom] ?')
    print(STRING in ['bem','bom'])
    print('\n the STRING contains "?" ?')
    print(STRING in '?')
```

#### i wanna check if the **string** contains some of these words

#### the output i wanna if the string are "*some string ?*" are

```py
    the STRING contains [tudo, ta OU esta] ?
    False

    the STRING contains [bem OU bom] ?
    False

    The string contains "?"
    True
```

#### but in all of the situations i get

```py
    the STRING contains [tudo, ta OU esta] ?
    False

    the STRING contains [bem OU bom] ?
    False

    The string contains "?"
    False
```

#### then... all False

#### what other methods to do this ( check if contains in string )

Comment: You're asking the question the wrong way around, `STRING` is not in your list, but elements of your list are in `STRING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking the question the wrong way around, `STRING` is not in your list, but elements of your list are in `STRING`.

Try this way instead:

```py
STRING = 'tudo, ta OU esta?'

words_to_find = ['tudo','ta','esta', 'chocolate']

for word in words_to_find:
    print(f'{word}: {word in STRING}')
```

Output:

```
tudo: True
ta: True
esta: True
chocolate: False
```